# Dropdown with stacked up- and down-arrows vs one down-arrow. What drives the choice?

Tags: dropdown, drop-down-list

Our team implemented non-native dropdown controls that use an up-triangle on top of a down-triangle (similar to the MacOS example).

1. The native controls (as far as I can tell) for MacOS (10.10) and Windows (7) are like this:

**MacOS**  [image: Image of MacOS native dropdown]

**Windows** [image: Image of Windows dropdown]

2. Amazon uses (at least here) a non-native dropdown that uses MacOS style "two triangles".

**Amazon**  [image: Amazon UI]

Is there any logic or meaning behind the decision to use one approach vs another? My advice to my team is simply to use a native control unless there is a compelling reason not to. But is there any logic behind which way to go when using a non-native control, or is this purely a matter of style?

Answer (score 2):

For new OS this is a way how dropdowns are displayed (it is probably also a concern for Apple designers - I do not know why it was changed).
For you - **it is best to use design it as close to native as possible**. For Mac - use  up/down icon, for Windows - triangle-down icon. All **because useres got used to it on their devices**.

For Windows users it will be confusing (and for Andorid may be aslo), since such up and down icons are used to increase or decrease number value in input (or time), for example in html:
http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-number